# Is it possible to have two forms displayed in two tabs but each in its own class?

Tags: 8, forms

I have a custom Profile Edit form, and then I want to add a Deactivate Account Form, displayed in a tab "Deactivate Account" in the custom "My Profile" page.

How do I render this Deactivate Account form in a tab of My Profile page?

Examples I've seen treat the form as one, which would result in a massive Form class.

Comment: Different tabs means different routes, if you aren't talking of tabs rendered via JavaScript or similar way.

Comment: You can put the forms in blocks and place them with a layout tool of your choice together on one page or for a code solution build a render array where you place two form builds inside of a tab element and return it from a controller.

Comment: @4k4 im pretty new to Drupal 8, could you provide an example?

Comment: The comments are more to clarify the question. As@kiamlaluno said the tabs used in the admin UI are links to different routes, [local tasks](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/menu-api/providing-module-defined-local-tasks). If you mean tabs controlled client side in javascript you can build such a layout as described in the second comment.